# Decode a byte array to a signed integer up to 64 bit

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, numbers

I know that JavaScript can't precisely represent all 64 bit integer numbers. But it can precisely represent numbers larger than 32 bit. And that's what I need. With whatever precision JavaScript can give me.

I have a byte array of known length. It has 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16 bytes. And it can contain a signed or unsigned integer, I know which it is. The data is big-endian (network byte order).

How can I get the number value from that byte array?

There are simple solitions that completely fail on negative numbers. There's DataView that isn't of any help with more than 32 bits. I'm interested in a nice and simple and preferable efficient pure JavaScript solution to handle this. There doesn't seem to be any solution for this in the part of the web that's visible to me.

In case somebody wants to see wrong code, here is my version of positive numbers:

```
function readInt(array) {
    var value = 0;
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        value = (value * 256) + array[i];
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what's the endianess of your array?

Comment: I have added my wrong code. The data is big-endian.

Comment: Why are you iterating backwards when it's big-endian?

Comment: As I said, this code doesn't work. I've copied it from another SO answer.

Comment: Have you tried just iterating the other way `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {` ? PS: It's not really your attempt or thought on the topic when you just copy it from another post and claim it's not working.

Comment: That doesn't work either and I wouldn't have expected that. If the numbers are multiplied and added all the time, how can I decode negative numbers?

Comment: I never said negative numbers would work with it, nor did you post the code as anything else than "version of positive numbers". To work for negative numbers, invert the negative number to a positive number (look at 2-complement and how signed int is stored). Then do the same you already did for positive numbers and change the sign afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](https://coderanch.com/t/406929/java/Convert-negative-integer-byte) explains a good and simple solution:

- Add up all bits from the right end, up to the second most significant bit.
- The most significant bit is not added as 2^i but as -2^i.

My code works in a larger scope that has an array and a pos to read from.

```
function readInt(size) {
    var value = 0;
    var first = true;
    while (size--) {
        if (first) {
            let byte = array[pos++];
            value += byte & 0x7f;
            if (byte & 0x80) {
                value -= 0x80;   // Treat most-significant bit as -2^i instead of 2^i
            }
            first = false;
        }
        else {
            value *= 256;
            value += array[pos++];
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

The raw bytes are provided in `array` (a `Uint8Array`) and `pos` is the next index to read. This function starts to read at the current `pos` and advances `pos` as it reads one of the `size` bytes.